# How to take data from a csv file? Angular 2

Tags: angular, csv

I'm new to Angular 2.

There are many questions related taking data from a CSV file. I want to implement this kind of feature using Angular 2. How should I proceed?

It's like: I want to create a new CSV file with some URLs. And then create a service for it and render data from URLs provided in the CSV file. But I'm not sure will it work? It would be great if anyone can suggest a better idea to implement this kind of feature. :)

Comment: Is it about "reading" and "processing" the csv file?

Comment: @thardes2 yes, something kind of "reading" and "processing" :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your environment, you could just download the file via [Angular 2's HTTP Client](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/angular-2-http) or if you're using NodeJs for example, you can read the [file from your hdd](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback).

Processing shouldn't be a problem, as you can go through the file line by line and split the line according to the used separator to get each field.

The next step depends on what you mean by

> render data from URLs

In an easy case you can just have a div and set the content, after you extracted your URL:

```
<div [innerHtml]="myUrlStuff">
</div>
....

export public class MyClass {

    public myUrlStuff:string;
    @Input() url: string;

    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.myUrlStuff = '';
        http.get(yourUrl).map((res) => this.myUrlStuff = res);
    }
}
```

You probably need some adjustments, this is just an example, which probably don't directy work.

Comment: like suppose, I add a URL which contains lots of articles (a type of RSS feed): then how should am I suppose to display that data?

Comment: Why are you using `@Input` here? I want to create it like a tab. Clicking on it will display RSS feed data from URL inside CSV file.

Comment: The input is for the data binding, you can also remove it and receive the data in a method or something similar. Have you at least tried the suggestion?

Comment: Thanks! No, I have not tried the suggestion. I will work on it today. :)